# How to check dynamic Input type with name attribute

Tags: jquery

How can I check dynamic input type with name. Below is my example

```
$("input:*[name=anyname]")
```

Above statement giving error

Where * could be any type of input control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `$("input[name=anyname]")`  it will select any input type.

Answer (score 3):

For any type of input use **[`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)**

> Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.

and attribute selector `[prop="value"]` for name,

```
$(':input[name="anyname"]')
```